# Putty: Network error : cannot assign requested address

Tags: excel, vba, putty

Hello I have written a macro to ssh to a server whose username and password are stored at A1 and B1 respectively. When the the macro gets invoked , putty throws error Network error : cannot assign requested address

```
Sub putty()
    Dim un As String, pwd As String, pcmd As String, pline As String
    Dim shellObj As Object, runCmd As Object, sOut As Object  

    un = Range("A1").Value
    pwd = Range("B1").Value
    Set shellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    pcmd = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe " & un & "@15.xx.xx.xx -pw " & 
    pwd & " who"
    Set runCmd = shellObj.exec(pcmd)
    Set sOut = runCmd.StdOut

    While Not sOut.AtEndOfStream
        pline = sOut.ReadLine
        Debug.Print pline
    Wend
End Sub
```

Is there any workaround for this.

Comment: I have put the snippet of the code

Comment: What happens if you take the output of `Debug.Print pcmd` and copy it into your shell and execute it. Does it work or does it throw the same error? • Try to replace your putty part  with `"""C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"" "` probably the space in `Program Files` is causing this issue.

Comment: I got the same error after using this  """C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"" "

Comment: Then answer my first question please.

Comment: Yaa debug is also giving the same error.

Comment: I was not asking if the debug gives an error I was asking if you get the same error when you take the result of `Debug.Print pcmd` and copy/past that into your shell and excecute it gives the same error in the shell? Can you please be more precise and confirm that?

Comment: can we chat over gmail or skype ?

Comment: I executed the code till it takes username from A1 , its working absolutely fine, the problem is from where it takes password from B1, then putty throws the error cannot assign requested address

Answer (score 1):

One option is to specify the port directly with `-P <port>` (e.g., `-P 22`), per the docs:
[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage)

It seems that the PuTTY UI displays the Port value as 22 by default, even if there is no "Default Settings" session stored in the registry, so it appears to be valid even though it is not.  The fix for this is to launch PuTTY, select the "Default Settings" and then click Load/Save.

EDIT:
This is a known bug in PuTTY 0.74 ([https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/pscp-port-0.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/pscp-port-0.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the default port is set correctly. If you open putty, the port field in "default settings" may not be empty